# Is MS SQL other than SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is MS SQL other than SQL Server ?

Comment: Even though the question is quite old you should clarify what you are referring to with *SQL Server* - product, term, ...?

Comment: On dba.stackexchange.com they refer (i.e. 'tag') the product 'Microsoft SQL-Server' as 'SQL-Server'. In this context the answer is 'yes'. In other context the anwer might be 'No'. So: It depends. In other words: Never rely on anybody understanding what you are talking about when you say 'SQL Server'.

Answer (score 3):

MS SQL and SQLServer are one and the same. MSSQL is the default instance name that it installs with.

Comment: I have my doubts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server ... Anyway, a major issue here is that Microsoft is naming their product "SQL Server", which makes it ambigous ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I'm not sure about your comment, especially on an answer that is getting towards 6 years old.... that is a disambiguation page for Wikipedia, in itself it means little. There is no "issue" with Microsoft calling their product "SQL Server" - they always have done so, since they bought the product called that on or around 1989. "SQL" is the technology it leverages, and it is a server product - no ambiguity there. As for the original question here, it is very poorly worded and we have to make assumptions about what the OP means, maybe you should leave a comment on the question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Fair enough, what I've tried to say is that the term *SQL Server* is a bit vague in itself, and brings at least for me no implication for a specific implementation (that is why I've added the wikipedia link) - hence the *issue* with the naming, as this leads to confusion. Additionally, the default instance name is *MSSQLSERVER*, which might be due to the age of the answer/question.

Answer (score 2):

MS SQL is the same product as SQL Server. The full name of the product is Microsoft SQL Server (usually followed by a year eg. 2008).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the questions I see online are based on the use of MS SQL server, so generally people take MS SQL to mean SQL server. However, that is not the case. Look at this:

> SQL Server: Generically, any database management system (DBMS) that can respond to queries from client machines formatted in the SQL language. When capitalized, the term generally refers to either of two database management products from Sybase and Microsoft. Both companies offer client-server DBMS products called SQL Server.
>   (http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/SQL_Server.html )

This means that SQL Server can mean any one of the client-server DBMS products from Sybase/Microsoft. But MS SQL server would specifically mean the Microsoft-based SQL server.

In spite of this, if you ask a question on SQL server, people would think you're implying MS SQL Server (since its rather popular).

Answer (score 1):

No.  Microsoft do have other database products, such as SQL Server Compact, but when people talk about "MS SQL," they almost invariably mean SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You may be conflating several different things:

- [Microsoft SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) - Microsoft's enterprise-level relational database management system,
- [Transact-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) (often referred to as *T-SQL*) - Microsoft's extension to the [Structured Query Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Both refer to the same [product](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah they are same product.